# Yii2 - update notification header count without reloading and receive notification every 10 sec

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

Everytime I send notification from my frontend to backend I still need to reload it to receive any new notification and everytime I read my notification the notification count disappears but when I reload the page the count comes back how do I make the status of my notification into already read from unread, and lastly how do I make it send me notification every time it checks new notification every 10 sec.

Here's my code:

```
**Backend TimeController:**

public function actionHeader()
    {   
        $inq = Inquiry::find()->where(['inquiry_status' => 1])->orderBy(['inquiry_id'=> 'DESC'])->count();
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON; 
        echo json_encode(["popup"=>$inq]);
}


**Header Notification Jquery, Ajax:**

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: '/backend/time/header',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
    console.log(data)
    if(data['popup'].length>0){
        notify(data['popup'][data['popup'].length-1]);       
    }          
}
});   
if($('.count').html()< 1){
    $('.count').html('');
    }
    $(document).on('click', '.notifications-menu .dropdown-toggle', function(){
       $('.count').html(''); 
       });

if (Notification.permission !== 'granted'){
        Notification.requestPermission();
    }
  });
function notify(data){
         var notification = new Notification('Received New Notification',{
             icon: '../img/building-icon.png',
             body: ' Client Name: '+data['client_name']+'\\n '+'Contact: '+data['contact_no']+'\\n '+'Email: '+data['emailadd'],
             });
         notification.onclick = function(){    
             window.open('/backend');
         } 
      setTimeout(function(){notification.close()}, 10000);    
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming our code is working try this. Attencion code not tested..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // "timer" for check notifications
     setInterval(function(){ checkNotification; }, 10000); //10000 miliseconds


    if($('.count').html()< 1){
        $('.count').html('');
    }
    $(document).on('click', '.notifications-menu .dropdown-toggle', function(){
       $('.count').html(''); 
       });

    if (Notification.permission !== 'granted'){
        Notification.requestPermission();
    }





  });
function notify(data){
     var notification = new Notification('Received New Notification',{
         icon: '../img/building-icon.png',
         body: ' Client Name: '+data['client_name']+'\\n '+'Contact: '+data['contact_no']+'\\n '+'Email: '+data['emailadd'],
         });
     notification.onclick = function(){    
         window.open('/backend');
     } 
  setTimeout(function(){notification.close()}, 10000);    
 }


 function checkNotification(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/backend/time/header',
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
            if(data['popup'].length>0){
                notify(data['popup'][data['popup'].length-1]);       
            }          
        }
    });   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your backend / backend / time / header you will have to make a query to know which notifications are seen or not seen.
And just after the notifications that have your query you must pass them to views

**Backend TimeController:**

```
     public function actionHeader()
            {   
                $inq = Inquiry::find()->where(['inquiry_status' => 1])-
                >orderBy(['inquiry_id'=> 'DESC']);
                $models=$inq->all();
                foreach ($models as $model) {
                    $model->inquiry_status=0;
                    $model->save();
                   }
                inq=inq->count();
                Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON; 
                echo json_encode(["popup"=>$inq]);
        }
```

> If I were you, I would guarantee it in a database in the state of the
>   notifications "falshed" and "vista" since I imagine that you do not
>   want
>
> flashed: to know if it has been shown to the user. view: to know if
>   the user clicked on it.

Done this you can make an ajax request like the one you have with a timeout of 10 seconds so that every 10 seconds you send a request to the server to see if there are new notifications

it would be something like that

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: '/backend/time/header',
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        if(data['popup'].length>0){
            notify(data['popup'][data['popup'].length-1]);       
        }          
    }


    if($('.count').html()< 1){
        $('.count').html('');
        }
        $(document).on('click', '.notifications-menu .dropdown-toggle', function(){
           $('.count').html(''); 
           });

    if (Notification.permission !== 'granted'){
            Notification.requestPermission();
        }
      })
 }, 10000);
    function notify(data){
             var notification = new Notification('Received New Notification',{
                 icon: '../img/building-icon.png',
                 body: ' Client Name: '+data['client_name']+'\\n '+'Contact: '+data['contact_no']+'\\n '+'Email: '+data['emailadd'],
                 });
             notification.onclick = function(){    
                 window.open('/backend');
             } 
          setTimeout(function(){
           notification.close()
       }, 10000);    
     }
});
```